# How can i detach elements and then show then with fadeIn / fadeOut on click

Tags: jquery

i would like to put a fadeIn fadeOut (instead of show/hide) , but when i tried the content jumps from where the prev element was residing , and i DO NOT want to use position absolute for the content. So how can i use animate in the same manner for the following ? So could i detach them on , then undo the detach on click ?

http://jsfiddle.net/ZM9dL/514/

```
$('.menu>li').on('click',function(e){
    $('.container>.'+ e.target.classList[0]).show().siblings().hide();
});
```

HTML

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li class="toggle1">One</li>
    <li class="toggle2">Two</li>
    <li class="toggle3">Three</li>
    <li class="toggle4">Four</li>
    <li class="toggle5">Five</li>
</ul>

<div class="container">
    <div class="toggle1">Here are the contents of 1..</div>
    <div class="toggle2" style="display:none;">Here are the contents of 2..</div>
    <div class="toggle3" style="display:none;">Here are the contents of 3...</div>
    <div class="toggle4" style="display:none;">Here are the contents of 4....</div>
    <div class="toggle5" style="display:none;">Here are the contents of 5.....</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `i DO NOT want to use position absolute for the content` that's the best solution: http://jsfiddle.net/ZM9dL/515/. Why do you not want to use it?

Comment: because the height of the div is dynamic and i can not set a height , and will always have other elements below it

Comment: There are ways around that, but without seeing your actual HTML it's hard to guide you.

Comment: You need to use absolute positioning to stop the content "jumping".  Just calculate the height of the div that you are going to be showing and then set the container to that height once the fadeIn is complete- http://jsfiddle.net/ZM9dL/520/

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution i have provided and its working. actually fade in and fade out animation needs delay to avoid the jerk between sibling elements. Where as in hide and show there is no delay in animation so it looks fine to you. Just edit the milliseconds as you want. by default i have put 200.

```
$('.menu>li').on('click',function(e){
var target = $('.container>.'+ e.target.classList[0]);
target.siblings().fadeOut(200);
target.delay(200).fadeIn() });
```

Comment: that jumps the content as well